# Rails thumbs_up error Validation failed: Voteable has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So thumbs_up does exactly what I want it to, but when I try to double vote I get this error `Validation failed: Voteable has already been taken` instead of being redirected to the previous page and Im not sure how to do that

Comment: I fixed it but I must wait 8 hours before posting the answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I dont know if its supposed to redirect automatically like Vote_fu does but I fixed it by adding an if/else in the controller to see if the current user has voted on the item or not.

```
unless current_member.voted_for?(@tattoo)
  current_member.vote_for(@tattoo)
  redirect_to :back
else
  redirect_to :back
end
```